# How can I get a Markdown or org-mode document outline in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, markdown, org-mode

I want something like the outline/navigator that you get in VS Code, which gives you a tree of the document headings. Can I get this in Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, in org-mode you can cycle between headings with `org-cycle` and `org-shifttab`, typically bound to <kbd>TAB</kbd> and S-TAB (backtab).  More generally, there is `outline-mode` which can be used in any an buffer to similar effect.

There is also `speedbar` or `sr-speedbar`, which provide tree-type views of files/directories, which may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Markdown mode](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) by J. Blevins provides this for markdown files out of the box. Just like with org-mode, the cycling is bound to `TAB` and `S-TAB`. You can install markdown mode from [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/markdown-mode).